# rails 3.1 link_to image_tag where image data is embedded as string

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, hyperlink, asset-pipeline

Ok  I am trying to convert the following  tag into a link_to statement that rails can understand.  can anyone send me in the right direction

I'm trying to convert this:

```
<li class="topmenu"><a href="/history" style="height:24px;line-height:24px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU.........." alt="History"/>History</a></li>
```

Into something like this:

```
<li class="top menu"><%= link_to "History" + image_tag(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU..........) %></li>
```

The above code obviously doesn't work, but there has to be a way.  any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this

```
<%=link_to image_tag("news.png") + "Newsletter", newsletter_path,:style => "height:24px;line-height:24px;"%>
```

There was no need for the block in the answer listed above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SASS you can use

```
asset-data-url("rails.png")
```

Take a look at the github repo and read the description:
https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#features